# Java heap space error

Tags: java, oracle, exception, out-of-memory

I get a  Java heap space error while running spring batch, with ibatis.

The following is the stack trace.

```
     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at oracle.sql.converter.CharacterConverter1Byte.toOracleStringWithReplacement(CharacterConverter1Byte.java:531)
at oracle.sql.CharacterSetWithConverter.convertWithReplacement(CharacterSetWithConverter.java:200)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion.javaCharsToCHARBytes(DBConversion.java:770)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion.javaCharsToCHARBytes(DBConversion.java:711)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIClob.write(T4C8TTIClob.java:384)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.putChars(T4CConnection.java:2708)
at oracle.sql.CLOB.putChars(CLOB.java:408)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleClobWriter.write(OracleClobWriter.java:111)
at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copy(FileCopyUtils.java:220)
```

Any idea what the sql converter is doing ?

Comment: It may simply need more memory. Increase the heap size (`-Xmx` flag), if not done already.

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077154/ways-to-reduce-memory-churn

Answer (score 0):

Also, as you are using Oracle JDBC, make sure that you have use ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY for your result sets - Oracle uses "a client-side cache" if you use scrollable ResultSets.
(http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/java.920/a96654/resltset.htm)